# Can an customised open source prject be protected by IP law

Tags: trademark

My designer created a logo for me using an open source design (with slight change). I wasn't aware of it uptill I visited colombia and saw a merchant selling T-shirt with the same design.

Now I want to know if I can get this logo registered as as a Trade Mark?

Comment: Dale M has answered your question but I would get in touch with your designer and get a refund if this isn't what you paid for.

Answer (score 1):

No

One of the criteria for registering a trade mark is that it be original. If someone has used it before you it cannot be registered.